# Verify the existence of a folder in SharePoint using the Graph API

Tags: sharepoint-online, graph-api

To check whether a specific path of a folder (e.g. `/Shared Documents/foo/bar`) exists in SharePoint, which endpoint of the Graph API can you use? If I use '[/search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-search?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)' with the word, 'bar', `/Shared Documents/foo/barista` is also matched unexpectedly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this request URL meets your needs, you get the shared document library by the endpoint:
`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/drives`
[image]

And you can get the subfolder in the document library by URL
`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/drives/{drive-id}/root:/{folderName}:/children`

and

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/drives/{drive-id}/root:/{folderName}:/{subfolderName}`

[image]

[image]

Hope this helps. Best Wishes.

Comment: Thank you for the post. I understood I had to fetch all path of the subfolders once although there are many subfolders in my case. I'll try to implement in this way.